# ¿Como definir que el espacio ya esta ocupado?

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un proyecto que hace unas reservas y quiero preguntar al usuario dónde quiere ubicarse(FILA/COLUMNA).

¿Cóomo puedo hacer para que diga que el puesto ya esta ocupado si alguien previamente lo reservo primero?

```
cout<<"\n Escoja su puesto por favor: \n";
cout<<"\n Digite el numero de la fila donde desea ubicarse: ";
cin>>a;
cout<<"\n Digite el numero de la columna donde desea ubicarse: ";
cin>>b; 
cout<<"\n Digite el numero de su documento (cc/ti): ";
cin>>Sur1[a][b].documento;
cout<<"\n Digite su nombre: ";
cin>>Sur1[a][b].nombre;
cout<<"\n Digite su apellido:";
cin>>Sur1[a][b].apellido;
cout<<"\n Digite su numero de telefono: ";
cin>>Sur1[a][b].telefono;
Sur1[a][b].ocupacion=1;
exito();
system("cls");
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta con chequear el estado de `ocupacion`. Si es distinto de 0 quiere decir que el puesto está ocupado.

```
cout<<"\n Escoja su puesto por favor: \n";

bool ok = false;
do
{
  cout<<"\n Digite el numero de la fila donde desea ubicarse: ";
  cin>>a;
  cout<<"\n Digite el numero de la columna donde desea ubicarse: ";
  cin>>b; 
  if( Sur[a][b].ocupacion != 0 )
    cout << "El sitio ya está ocupado\n";
  else
    ok = true;
} while (!ok);
```

Comment: le asigno el valor de 1 si se le ocupa, mi idea es que si ya esta en 1 y desean volver a ocuparlo como se haria para decir que ya esta ocupado. sin necesidad de utilizar bool.

Comment: @PedroAntonioObregonAlomia Ya está corregido, no vi la variable `ocupacion`

Comment: con esa variable unicamente me dice que ya esta ocupado el espacio. mi pregunta es ¿Como hacer para que diga que ya a sido ocupado previamente por otra persona?

Comment: @PedroAntonioObregonAlomia Lo que tienes que hacer es inicialiar esa variable a 0 al inicio del programa... y asignarle el valor 0 también cuando el sitio se libera.

Comment: De acuerdo gracias!